# C++ cin.get(), cin.peek() pausing, same with stdio

Tags: c++, get, wait, cin, istream

This is my code as it is currently. This code coughs up the error on the cin.get(). I understand it isn't good code, it was never supposed to be, I was simply testing some cin things.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c[1000];
    cin.setstate(cin.eofbit);
    cout << cin.good() << endl;
    cout << cin.eof() <<endl;
    cout << cin.get() << endl;
    cin.putback('c');
    cout << cin.get() << endl;
    cout << "Do we ever reach this?" << endl;
    while(1){
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway. My issue is cin.get(), cin.peek(), cin.ignore(), getchar(), or pretty much any cin or stdio function you can name pauses the execution of my program when the stream is empty, without setting EOF bits or anything. This is irritating for me, as I want to check whether there is anything in the stream so I can clear it, as ignore() always pauses.

The only method I can get to work is 'istream::readsome'. I've loaded this into a char array and printed it using cout. It prints a long string of symbols I don't recognise (Each one of these is an individual symbol).

http://gyazo.com/e3ee65cdad7ed5cc7b2ce2307ca58c90

Cast to an integer, these come out as -52, which doesn't equate to anything in either ASCII or Unicode.

I am compiling using Visual C++ Express 2010.

Please help, I'm utterly stumped at this point. I simply want to read chars/flush my stream, without pausing if nothing is there. I've spent a good 3 hours trying to solve this. Sigh.

Comment: `sync()` discards anything left in the buffer, but that behaviour is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it. But is there any guaranteed way, or a way to prevent the awful pausing if I DO cin.ignore or cin.peek?

Comment: OTOH, by properly checking the results of your I/O operations, you shouldn't ever come to a point where you don't know if the stream is empty or not.

Comment: But I'm not sure how I can properly check if I can't check what's left in the stream without accidentally pausing my program. Plus, it should still set the EOF bit shouldn't it? That's simply just not being set.

Comment: To set the EOF bit from the console, type `Ctrl + Z`.

Comment: That's not what I mean though Jesse. When I try to extract a character from an empty stream, rather than setting the EOF bit (As it says it should on cplusplus.com), it sits around waiting for input. Even when I'm only peeking at the next character.

Comment: @user1819357: Right, that is what it is supposed to do (I don't know what cplusplus.com says though). I don't understand why `std::getline` and `std::string` wouldn't be sufficient though.

Comment: It looks like they'll have to be, I just wanted the extra flexibility afforded by being able to attempt to read the stream without seizing up the whole program. Imalso just trying to understand why its seemingly misbehaving. Could it be a compiler issue?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of all characters known to be available, you can use `std::istream::ignore()` in combination with `std::streambuf::in_avail()`:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
```

However, I guess that this doesn't really do what you want: The standard stream objects just read whatever the operating system hands them. Typically, the default mode for input connected to some sort of console window is to line-buffer the input. How many characters are really handed to the stream is pretty much undefined.

To check whether there is input available on the input stream, you need need to use platform specific methods. The standard C++ library doesn't provide any non-blocking check to see if new data arrived on `std::cin`. On POSIX system you can just use `poll()` with file descriptor `0` to see if `std::cin` has any data. What is needed on non-POSIX systems I don't know.

Comment: I had a fiddle around with this. IN_avail always returned 1, regardless of how many characters I putback into cin. The. Only way to clear it furthermore was with a sync(). Plus ignore decides to pause things, sigh. Thanks for the response though, Ill keep digging for something able to check it in windows

Comment: @user1819357 did you find a way to check on Windows?